# How to make tab completion work within parentheses

Tags: bash, tab-completion

On my Ubuntu machine, I can do this

```
emacs $(which first-part-of-executable<tab>
```

and bash will tab-complete the full executable name. I enabled this myself by adding

```
complete -c which
```

to my `.bashrc`, because I only want `which` to complete with executable names.

For some reason, on my RHEL5 machine, the tab completion works for `which` within the `$(`, but then moves back to filename completion for the executable.

How can I make bash complete `which` *within* parentheses?